# Select a string between two known strings and output greater than one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select in between `|` and length should be greater than one.

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)

set @c = 'Leslie|Nicole|McCrory'

SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('|', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), '')))
```

Result : Nicole

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)

set @c = 'Leslie|N|McCrory'

SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('|', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), '')))
```

Result : N

I need the result, which should be greater than one. (i.e) Leslie|N|McCrory => from this N should not be selected.

Comment: What's the expected resut?

Comment: Output result should be greater than one. Say "Leslie|N|McCrory" => N should not selected @FelixPamittan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)

set @c = 'Leslie|N|McCrory'

SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('|', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), '')))
WHERE LEN(SUBSTRING(STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), ''), 0, CHARINDEX('|', STUFF(@c, 1, CHARINDEX('|',@c), '')))) > 1
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you may want to put the substring method in a subquery, so you only have to do it once